# How to run smart contract using go-ethereum source code?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

*mycontract.sol*

> pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
>
> contract HelloWorld {
>
> uint256 counter = 100;
>
> function add() public { 
>     counter++;
>   }
>
> function subtract() public { 
>    counter--;
>   }
>   }

I used solcjs to compile a contract and get the binary of the contract in hex:

> solcjs --bin mycontract.sol

then I put the hex value in the

> /go-ethereum/core/vm/runtime/run_example_test.go/ExampleExecute()

function as the code parameter of runtime.Execute().
Then I run

> run_example_test.go

But it return an array of number:
[image]

So I think that's how to run smart contract using geth source code but **what if I want to run some specific function of the contract ? And how can I get the state(or the return of contract) of the contract ?**